# I cant get my javascript array to work anymore

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Please let me know what I am doing wrong so that I can fix this. I had it working before but changed something and now it's broken again

```
var myArray = [];

function byId(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
myArray[0] = {
    name: "John",
    value: "Doe"
};
myArray[1] = {
    name: "Jane",
    value: "Dew"
};
myArray[2] = {
    name: "James",
    value: "Dot"
};
myArray[3] = {
    name: "Jack",
    value: "Dax"
};

//for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    //alert(myArray[i].name + '/' + myArray[i].value);
//}

var text = [], 
for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   text.push( myArray[i].name + '/' + myArray[i].value);
}

byId("full").innerHTML = text.join('<br/>');
```

Comment: What does firebug say? What error do you get? How does it "not work"?

Comment: you realise your arrays are global, right?

Comment: [JSLINT](http://www.jslint.com/) Use it.

Comment: No offense, but I'm voting to close this question due to a typo.

Answer (score 5):

```
var text = [],
```

See this comma? Replace it with a semicolon:

```
var text = [];
```

Comment: thanks this was really helpful and I missed it

Comment: @user3174713, glad I could help. Please set the question as solved by accepting my answer.